# Open 2 windows of team explorer in visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio, team-explorer

is it possible to open 2 team explorer windows in a visual studio?

I want to have the **Pending changes** and the **Work Item** windows open in tabs, Like the **server explorer** and **team explorer** are opened.

Thank you!

Comment: No, but VS2013 supports breaking them out into their own windows.

Comment: @SteveAndrews please add it as a answer so I can mark the question as answered :). Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't open multiple Team Explorer windows, but in Visual Studio 2013 you can undock the Pending Changes and Builds tabs using the breakout button in the top right. More information here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/11/03/team-explorer-everywhere-2013-is-available.aspx